# How to "dress up" a CV that has a PhD but no peer reviewed publication record?

Tags: job-search, cv

I have a glaring omission in my CV because I do not have any scholarly (peer reviewed) publications to my credit. However, I have good industry-based experience (more than 10 years when I have written a number of manuals and submissions), and have recently completed a Social Science PhD from a reputable university. I am after some guidance on ways in which a person in my position would address this glaring omission in a CV so as to better highlight/present his credentials for academic purposes (e.g. to apply to join a university etc).

Comment: How have you completed a Social Science PhD without any publication?

Comment: Yes, for the sole reason that I was employed full-time (in a good job) during the duration of the study so there was really no great need to publish in terms of a career move etc.

Comment: But PHD = publications in most of the countries I know. You cannot get a PHD just by passing some courses.

Comment: No, some universities don't require any publication record. I completed it from a nationally recognised / reputable university and it was not a requirement.

Comment: While there might be no requirement to have published anything, there is (as far as I know) a requirement that the dissertation is of sufficient quality that it (or at least parts of it) could be published. This might be a way to get at least an item on the publication list (remember to mark it as not yet peer-reviewed until it has been).

Comment: You seem to be unnecessarily vague.  You have said repeatedly that the university is "reputable".  Can you not name the university?  Is your PhD in "Social Science" or is there a specific social science that you focused on?  Some details might help.  Avoiding the details leads people to assume you are being less than honest, and that the university is anything but "reputable", which makes it difficult to paint yourself in a positive light

Comment: @rotard: On this site, avoiding certain details can help to generate answers which are more broadly applicable.  It can be tough to figure out which details to include and which to submit.  In my interactions on this site I have come to believe that in order to get a useful answer one should include (i) one's academic field [how finely depends on the question] and (ii) one's geographic region, at least at the level of North America / Europe / Asia and so forth.  Naming one's exact university is something I like to see more in *answerers* than *questioners*.

Comment: @Pete: generally, I agree.  However, in this case I think it is relevant, since while both Harvard and University of Phoenix Online can be called "reputable", they really aren't the same.  For example, Harvard I would name-drop while UPO I would not

Comment: @rotard: I would be surprised if "reputable university" referred to either Harvard or UPO.  I agree that a more precise term -- e.g. "Top X", "Research I", "public research university" -- would be more helpful.

Comment: In my view, naming my university or discipline has no bearing on my question. It would only divert attention away from the question I have asked.

Comment: @Alexandros IMHO, having publications is not mandatory to get a PhD, however it will greatly improve your chances to get a job in academia.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have submitted manuscripts to peer-reviewed outlets, you can say so.  If you have anything under second-round review, be sure to say so because that's all the better.

If you haven't submitted manuscripts, you could do so.  One of my peer-reviewed publications was originally a paper I wrote for a Ph.D. seminar.  I blew the dust off, firmed it up and made it stronger, and I submitted it.  It was a nice little paper.  My point is that you have doubtless done work that you could turn into a submission with X weeks of work.

Lots of people list their current research projects under a title such as "Current Research."

Beware that search committees know all the tricks.  You're not going to fool anyone.  But, I'm sure your goal is not to "fool" anyone at all.  You just want to put your best foot forward, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: +1 For _Current Research_ and _put your best foot forward_.

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely write up your ideas/manuscripts as publishable manuscripts if you haven't already. After reshaping the manuscripts so that they are ready for submission, I would also suggest that you post them as preprints online (if journals in your field allows this), preferably to a preprint server. Depending on your field there are e.g. arXiv, peerJ, SSRN (most relevant for you), and biorxiv. This will allow you link to the paper, so that people can evaluate by themselves if your manuscripts contain good research. This is also a way of showing that there is actually a finished well-structured manuscript, and not just a manuscript title on your CV.

In my mind, your best bet would be to fix manuscripts, submit to journal + upload to preprint server, and include on CV as *submitted manuscript* along with a preprint link. As the previous answer stated, also make sure to update the status of manuscripts when they go out for review/revision. Just be sure that you are honest in how you present the status of your manuscripts.

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure, that your university has archived your thesis. In doing this it is always a citable work. In some countries it is also a very common requirement to obtaining a Ph.D. (or any equivalent), that the thesis itself has to be published in some form. The variations tend to range from books (registered with ISBN), digital copy (pdf-A), hardcopies at differnt libraries, or also microfilm. Hence the problem is more a problem of accessibility.

As these kind of publications are not peer reviewed, and accessibility is a limiting factor, they are usually referred to as 'grey literature'.

When publishing results of your original thesis, what you should probably also do, you might want to cite your dissertation at some point in this work. The library of your university (or equivalent institution) will certainly keep track of dissertations and you can ask them about how to cite them. (Also a good starting point is trying to find this work via some search engines.)

In your CV you will also mention from which university and when you received your Ph.D. Depending on how deep you will go into this, you might mention the title, probably a short summary of the field you were working in.

There are also a lot of print-on-demand publishers that are specialized in thesis. However, this might not be the best solution, but it would be another way to make it citable.